# What are all the possible prepositions after the sentence "to do research"?

Tags: prepositions

If you'd use a preposition after the pattern "to do research...", what would be all the potential prepositions that could come after?

Edit: I'm speaking about researching something of a little value, not a social subject or a scientific matter or anything, more like a *research (insert preposition here) new pc games or online products*.

Comment: Nobody says "_a_ research". It is a mass noun. That is a common error coming from L1-L2 interference.

Comment: We don't *do **a** research* in English ... we *do research on* or *into a topic*, or simply *research a topic*.

Comment: @Cascabel Thanks, corrected.

Comment: I can do research:into technology; in a matter of minutes; to the beat of a drum; for the government; down to the last detail; with a glad heart; between lunch and dinner; and [many many more](https://www.talkenglish.com/vocabulary/top-50-prepositions.aspx). You will have to be a bit more specific about what you want.

Comment: What if I'm talking about something of a much smaller value? Like, I need to have a list of prices for all the cotton t-shirts sold online and I need someone to research that, but I need a preposition.

Comment: Can you edit the question to say that please?

Comment: _Research_ as a verb is usually transitive, so it takes a direct object. If you include "do" with the _noun_, it is another ball of wax, and possibly idiomatic, depending on the object of the preposition.

Comment: @Cascabel Idioms are outlaw!

Comment: On, for, about, from, into, during, including, against, among, despite, concerning, without, beyond.  And many more.

Answer (score 3):

The noun research is followed by the preposition in when the object of the preposition is a field of research, for example:

> The professor was renowned for her research in biology.

Possible prepositions include (each of them have a different meaning):

- to do research *in/into* biology
- to do research *for* biology
- to do research *before* biology
- to do research *about* biology
- to do research *throughout* biology

**These are just some common prepositions (they all have different meanings), a list of the top 50 can be viewed [here](https://www.talkenglish.com/vocabulary/top-50-prepositions.aspx)**.

## With the edit

> I'm speaking about researching something of a little value, not a social subject or a scientific matter or anything, more like a research (insert preposition here) new pc games or online products.

You could use:

- to do research *in/into* PC games
- to do research *about* PC games

Comment: "to do research of biology" is incorrect. You could do research 'of the highest quality", but not that.

Comment: @DJClayworth i was thinking it sounded a bit off, removed it

Comment: ...and you really should point out that they don't all mean the same. To do research *before* biology is to do some before I take my biology class.

Comment: @DJClayworth edited post

Comment: What about "*to do research **about** biology*" here, what does it mean? Does it mean the same as when "in/into" are used?

Comment: @Enthusiastor yes it does

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-exhaustive list of prepositions that follow *research*, based on a Corpus of Contemporary American English search for "research" followed by a preposition. The general impression should be that, if you can think of a preposition, you can likely use it with research.

[image]

Here's a further breakdown using the *top relevant result* in each of these entries. Little surprise that the preposition's meaning *highly influences the resulting collocation*:

- research **on** *his father's experience in the war* (topic of research, here specific)
- research **in** *research in immunology and cell therapy* (topic of research, here field- or subject-level)
- research **at** *the University of Manchester* (place of research)
- research **into** *your opponent* (topic of research)
- research **for** *clients* / *my book* (audience or purpose of research)
- research **by** *a private-sector guy in Great Britain* (author)
- research **with** *people that regularly eat hot dogs* (study group or target)
- research **of** *GASe stability in air* / *Vaghi and colleagues* (topic of research OR authors of research)

This list could keep on going for a while. Other prepositions to denote the topic of research include *about*, *regarding*, *over*, and *concerning*. You'll want to look up each collocation yourself to get a better idea of whether it's appropriate for your context.